# Histogram of fixed sample with repetition in R - something wrong

Tags: r, probability

I have a list of numbers (101 numbers )-

```
    > asnum<-as.numeric(as.character(unlist(data[[1]])))
> asnum
  [1]   7.1652348   5.6665965   4.4757553   4.8497086  15.2276296  -0.5730937   4.9798067
  [8]   2.7396933   5.1468304  10.1221489   9.0165661  65.7118194   5.5205704   6.3067488
```

I need to sample 1000 observations, save the sample and draw a histogram of it.

I wrote this code-

```
    set.seed(1) #save my sample
sample_1000_times<-sample(asnum,1000, replace=TRUE)#sample 1000 times with replace
hist(sample_1000_times)
```

but it does not looking good.

[image: this is my hist]

and I need to do it like this -

[image: without the normal distribution curve, but with this limits on X and Y]

any help?

Comment: any help?..please

Comment: what do you mean it does not look good? can you add a picture of the plot to your question?

Comment: Its need to be symetric no?. Because the plot doesnt look symetric..

Comment: any help? please.

Comment: Are the numbers in `asnum` normally distributed? If it is not, then `sample(asnum)` will also not be normally distributed.

Comment: no, we don't have any information that its normally distributes.first, I just need to sample n observestions  with replace and by this way I need to estimate my theta- by this sample. than, I need to sample 1000 observations with replace and create the  hist.

Comment: it comes from a distrubution with speaical function

Comment: Any help?.. i dont know